# How to highlight cells in excel based on the cell above it?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel Workbook, in which I have some information. What I actually want to know is if there is a way to highlight cells in a columns which have the word "Additional" in the cell above it.

For example there is a cell F8 which has "Additional" in it, so I would like to highlight F9. Similarly if Additional appears in F73, I would like to highlight F71 and so on.

[image: Example Image]

Any help in this would be appreciated.

Thanks.
~K

Comment: Search for "conditional formatting in Excel" - you will get a lot of examples and tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in CF rule

```
=F1="Additional"
```

and apply to from `F2` cell like `F2:F5000`. See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This worked totally. Thanks. Just to add another thing I did was that I applied conditional formatting on one cell and then went to manage rules again and selected the range from that little button to the right (Under applies to) - I am using Office 365.